# Substitute() the contents of variable within function

Tags: r, substitution

I am trying to make a function that takes a grouped tbl (or any other data concept) and loop across all of each grouped tbl.

It will be called like so:

```r
mydata |>
  filter( a > 10 ) |>
  group_by(zig) |>
  myfunc()
```

Inside it, I have something like:

```r
    if (dplyr::is_grouped_df(.data)) {

    model <- list()
      levels = dplyr::group_keys(.data)[[1]] 
      col = dplyr::group_vars(.data) |> as.character()

      for (i in levels) {
        # print(eval(select(.data,substitute(col)  == substitute(i) ))
        # print(.data[substitute(col)== substitute(i),])
    }
   }
```

The two commented lines does not work, and I tried a few iterations. I cant make dplyr::select or the data.table syntax detect that they should be filtering by the contents of col and i, not by col and i itself.

If it is not clear, col holds the name of the column I want to filter the data and i is holding the level to which I want the data filtered by.

- What am I missing there?

Comment: What is the desired output? Are you trying to recreate the existing `group_split` function? Or maybe `group_map`?

Comment: sounds like group_split is what I want, will look into it. I want small data sets based in the existing groups.

Comment: Ok, group_split is what I want, could you convert your comment into an answer so I can accept it? Thanks